# Subsetting Shapefiles by setting a numerical threshold on attributes in R

Tags: r, attributes, subset, shapefile, threshold

I am trying to subset a shapefile by a numerical attribute in R.

I have a shapefile (deforestation) with attribute (area) and I want to select only area > 1 ha. How can I do that?

Comment: I am trying to subset by a range of numerical values (area > 1 ha) not just for a single value.

Comment: You can filter or subset the `sp` or `sf` object like a regular data frame.

Comment: area <- subset(deforestation, area == ">1")
plot(area)

Comment: Thank you but not really working with the ">" sign. I am trying to subset by a range of values  above 1 ha.

Comment: You did not provide any reproducible data. There is nothing I can do.